# Промис не успевает резолвиться в цикле

Tags: javascript, promise

```
var thisTypeTabs = _.filter(tabs, function (tab) {
    return this.isRelativeTabType(thisTypeTab.typeId, tab.typeId);
    //возвращает undefined, т.к промис еще не отрезолвился
}, this);

private isRelativeTabType(selectedTabType, tabTypeForCheck) {
    if (selectedTabType === tabTypeForCheck) {
        return true;
    }

    this.TypeConfigurationProvider.getTypeConfig(tabTypeForCheck).then(config => {
        return _.indexOf(config.BaseFullTypeNames, selectedTabType) > -1;
    });
}
```

Как можно обеспечить правильный порядок выполнения кода? Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не обращать внимание на другие странности кода, то, очевидно, вы делаете `return` не там, где хотите. Но такой код всё равно работать не может, вы должны понимать, что Promise возвращает ответ асинхронно и передаёт его в коллбэк `.then()`, и в вашем случае внутри `filter` всегда будет true, т.к. возвращённый объект `Promise` существует. А вот например метод [Promise.filter](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.filter.html), похоже в вашем случае это то, чем нужно заменить `filter` underscore.